# Have i pass the same object with prepareForSegue back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue

i've got some `segue` created in storyboard. It has some identifier. I configure `destinationViewController` and assign some object as property of this `destinationViewController` in method `prepareForSegue:sender:`. This object is also property of my controller which called `segue`. In `destinationViewController` i've got `BarButtonItem` and when i press it, I call other `segue` and i go back to previous view. And when I'm in this viewController, property with this object which was passed to `destinationViewController` is equal to `nil`. Is possible to do something like this? :

1. When i'm in `SourceViewController` which has `someProperty` I set property of `DestinationViewController`.
2. When i'm back from `DestinationViewController` my property `someProperty` in `SourceViewController` isn't null - it should be the same as before switching viewController.

It's possible?

Now i've got to pass `someObject` from `A` to `B` and when I'm switching views I have to pass `someObject` from `B` to `A` - the same object.

Thank you for response and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not using another segue when you return to another view. You should be able to dismiss the current view whether its using a navigation controller or in a modal. As for you needing the same object, keep a reference to the object in controller A when you pass it to controller B. Both controllers will have a reference to the same object so making a change to it in controller B will show up in your object reference in controller A automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I used `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. Work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should really not do this and the reason is when you go back to SourceViewController it will actually create a NEW VC and push that on the stack so your stack will end up 'SourceVC, DetailVC, SourceVC' probably not what you want! You will probably want your navigation controller to pop the DetailVC ([`self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES]`)

As for the property. It depends what the property is and if you have more, but according to MVC pattern there is a good chance you actually want to create a model class that handles this variable for you. Then when you push to the DetailVC you pass a reference to your model and the DetailVC can access that variable through the model (getting or setting) then when you pop back to the SourceVC it can use the reference to the model that it already has to retrieve the newly set property.